# Custom formatter for PhoneNumber in Java

Tags: java, spring, annotations, customization

I'am trying to create the custom annotation for phone-number formatting.

```
 @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 public @interface ContactNumberFormate {
 }
```

BeanPostProcessor realisation:

```
 @Component
public class PhoneFormatter implements BeanPostProcessor {

private Object beanIs;

private PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String s) throws BeansException {
    if (bean.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(ContactNumberFormate.class)) {
        beanIs = bean.getClass();
    }
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String s) throws BeansException {
    String phone = "";
    String locale = "";
    try {
        phone = (String) beanIs.getClass().getDeclaredField("phone").get(bean);
        locale = (String) beanIs.getClass().getDeclaredField("locale").get(bean);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Other code//

    return formattedPhoneNumber;
  }

 }
```

But for "beanIs = bean.getClass()" I catch NullPointedException

Full log:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.spb.dreamwhite.util.phoneUtil.PhoneFormatter.postProcessAfterInitialization(PhoneFormatter.java:33)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
```

Comment: You can refer to this git repository. https://github.com/loneil/custom-phone-number-formatter

Comment: please paste your full exception log